# Maven Eclipse Debug "JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)"

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, maven, jboss-weld

I'm trying to debug Maven tests in Eclipse. When I launch tests with the maven option maven.surefire.debug, I get this error :

```
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:690]
/bin/sh: line 1: 27500 Abort trap
```

It is the same when I tried tu launch debug in my shell.

I tried to add the maven option forkMode=never, and I get another error with my weld artifact that I do not have without the maven.surefire.debug option :

```
Error loading Weld bootstrap, check that Weld is on the classpath
```

However, Weld is on my classpath.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I found the solution. The port I used for debug was already in use, probably due to a bug of maven. When using maven.surefire.debug, maven waits on a port. I killed it once, and then retryed to relaunch the maven test. The solution is to close the opened port (I restarted my machine, but there may be a less radical solution...)

Comment: You can post this as your own solution and then accept it a day later.

Comment: @RémiDoolaeghe Can you share the solution. I'm currently facing same error.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To kill a process listening on a port:

This command should list processes listening on all ports:

```
netstat -ano
```

The `-o` option will display the process id.

If you're using a *nix system, you can refine a little further with:

```
netstat -ano | grep <badport>
```

When you have the process id, you can terminate it with:

Windows:

- Open Task Manager, add the PID column with View > Select Columns > PID
- Find the process and right-click to kill it

Others:

```
kill <PID>
```

Comment: Sorry, but the -o option is not recognized. I work on a MacOS 10.6. The solution seems to be a good idea, though.

Comment: I think you may be able to get this info on OS X with 'sudo lsof -i -P'

Comment: You are right. sudo lsof -i -P | grep <bad_port> works fine. Thank you.

Comment: In Ubuntu, I add `netstat -anop` to list out pid.

Comment: If it helps hunting down the correct process to kill, I found the java process in question listening on port `5005`. I also see that it was executed as command like `java -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 -jar xxxxxx`

Comment: I'm used to killing the "Java" process, but this time I was tricked because this time the process was called "OpenJDK Platform binary" so I didn't find it by a simple alphabetical sort. This answer helped, thanks.

Answer (score 13):

**For Mac users:**

Usually the problem is that another process keeps Maven debug port 5005 open.
So I checked which process keeps this port open by executing:

```
lsof -i tcp:5005
```

The output was:

```
COMMAND  PID        USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    9089 my_user    7u  IPv4 0xe88ec542fd4cffc9      0t0  TCP *:avt-profile-2 (LISTEN)
```

And then I killed the process:

```
kill -9 9089
```

If you want these 2 process to be able to run together, you'll have to change the Maven debug port of at least one of them.
See: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/debugging.html.

Answer (score 5):

Go to `Debug configuration` -> `Remote Java Application` -> `Connect` tab, check `Allow termination of remote JVM`.

Then, when you are going to restart the server/maven, go to `Debug perspective` and click the `read / stop` button.....

Answer (score 5):

There is a long time the question was asked but i had the same problem recently.

1. Open Task Manager
2. Kill all "java.exe" process
3. Relaunch the mvn debug

Hope it will help

Answer (score 3):

Just for documentation, I had the exact same error, running on my local:

> ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
>   FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
>   ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)

in my case the port wasn't the issue, but the host file. The solution is to add/re-add/uncomment:

> 127.0.0.1      localhost

The config file sets `localhost` as default, so a solution is add that host or change it for a custom one.

Answer (score 1):

To add on.. I had the similar issue last week, when debugging using eclipse was made impossible.

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized,
jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_LOAD(196)
ERROR: transport library not found: dt_socket
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_LOAD(509)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_LOAD(196): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:690]
```

Sadly non of the solution I can possibly find online was helpful.

The issue turned out to be that somehow firewall removed all the dlls in my JRE bin... (so dt_socket.dll went completely missing).

Reinstalling the entire JRE helped.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to me was removing the breakpoints of project! If you have many branches and changed recently sometimes eclipse lost some's breakpoints.

Comment: this actually is helpful, I was struggling for weeks, was able to only run not debug

Answer (score 0):

first of all remove all debug points in eclipse

search for PID with server port
netstat -ano|find /i "7001"
replace 7001 with your port number in above line

sample o/p
C:\Users\shaithal>netstat -ano|find /i "7001"
TCP    127.0.0.1:51340        127.0.0.1:7001         SYN_SENT        17396

then kill that process
taskkill /F /PID 17396

search for PID with debug port also
netstat -ano|find /i "8453"
8453 is debug port in my case replace 8453 with your port number in above line

sample o/p

C:\Users\shaithal>netstat -ano|find /i "8453"
TCP    0.0.0.0:8453           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       19904

then kill that process
taskkill /F /PID 19904

Answer (score 0):

it was the host file adding below

127.0.0.1 localhost

fixed

Answer (score 0):

This kind of weird problems can also be caused by **VPN connections**