# mvnDebug fails with a permission denied

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I am trying to debug my project, built with maven, on a new system. The command `mvn tomcat:run` runs fine but however, it fails with `mvnDebug tomcat:run`.

```
C:\project>mvnDebug tomcat:run
Preparing to Execute Maven in Debug Mode
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Permission denied
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:690]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
```

The plugin defined in pom.xml is:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </plugin>
```

I am unable to find a solution that explains the issue with a "Permission denied". I did find a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428333/maven-eclipse-debug-jdwp-transport-dt-socket-failed-to-initialize-transport-in?rq=1)on SO, but it had a "Address already in use" issue.

Comment: Do you have a firewall running, or is something already bound to that port?

Comment: No special firewall, just the one provided with Windows 7. However, when I first ran mvnDebug, I got a prompt regard a block or unblock. I think I might have hit block.

Comment: but I cannot find any entries for mvnDebug in the firewall blocked list

Comment: to make it work, i did a "Restore Defaults" in `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Firewall`. It still doesn't work

Comment: even turning off the firewall doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried using another port? By default it binds to `8000`.

Comment: Omg...i think should take a nap... :)

Comment: It works when I change the port... Thanks

Comment: No problem! I can add it as answer, if you'd like. Or you can delete the question; whichever works for you.

Comment: sure, add it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible that something else is bound to port `8000`, or it might be blocked somehow. Try using another port and see if you are able to bind to that. There are details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935375/debugging-in-maven). Basically you have to change the `mvnDebug.bat` batch-file to use another port.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was because of the port being excluded in Windows:

```
netsh int ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp
```

I resolved it after executing the following command:

```
net stop winnat
```

reference: https://superuser.com/a/1610009/84873

Answer (score 0):

Reason for this issue to come could be that your port 8000 is blocked or used some where else.

For me, restarting of machine has fixed this issue.

Thanks