# Unable to start debugging a java application using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jvm

I have a java application which I am trying to debug using eclipse. When I launch debugging, I see this error message in the console:

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=JVMTI_ERROR_INTERNAL(113)
ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection refused ["transport.c",L41]
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510) ["debugInit.c",L500]
JDWP exit error JVMTI_ERROR_INTERNAL(113): No transports initialized
```

I am NOT trying to remotely debug the java application. My java application is set up as a project in eclipse itself. I created a debug configuration and attempted to launch the application using it.

Having looked at various options on this forum, I tried pinging localhost and 127.0.0.1. Both of them have succeeded (pinged with no issues). I do not have a clue on why this is happening.

The debugging is however working for a simple test class!

At the time of failure, this is what I see in eclipse log:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.7.0_71
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_IE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

org.eclipse.jdt.launching
Error
Mon Dec 29 15:24:26 GMT 2014
Cannot connect to VM

com.sun.jdi.connect.TransportTimeoutException
    at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.SocketTransportService.accept(SocketTransportService.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.SocketTransportImpl.accept(SocketTransportImpl.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.SocketListeningConnectorImpl.accept(SocketListeningConnectorImpl.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.StandardVMDebugger$ConnectRunnable.run(StandardVMDebugger.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

- Eclipse versions used: Luna (4.4.1), Indigo (3.7.2) - both of them are failing
- JDK version configured for the project: jdk1.5.0_15
- Operating System: Windows 7, 64 bit
- Firewall: none
- Tried launching eclipse using -vm argument in eclipse.ini, pointing to JRE 1.6.0_20. That didn't work either

Can someone please guide me on what the issue could be.

Appreciate any help. Thank you.

Ravi.

Comment: I would suggest to remove the debug configuration for this application and do it again from scratch: 1) from `run` menu: `debug configurations...` then look for your application and click the red `X`, then `close`. 2) right-click on your main class and select `debug as...` / `Java Application`.

Comment: Also see these two questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428333/maven-eclipse-debug-jdwp-transport-dt-socket-failed-to-initialize-transport-in?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612986/eclipse-jdwp-error-when-trying-to-debug?rq=1

Comment: Thanks @geert3. I have tried removing and recreating the run/debug configurations, Creating a new workspace, Setting up the project again. Neither of them worked!

Comment: @geert3. I did take a look at the links/questions that you've provided. One of them is related to the usage of a port (that is already in use) for remote debug. I am not remote debugging my application. And the other one is related to the usage of anti virus. I did some investigation from the anti virus intrusion into my development platform - did not find anything suspicious (yet). Thanks for your suggestions, again.

Comment: Do you have anything uncommon in your application? do you start a socket listener or somehting else java has to initialize different from the simple test class that you could debug?

Comment: From the error it looks an awful lot like Eclipse is somehow trying to remote debug. Can you stop the process occupying that port and see if you get any further? I'm out of ideas otherwise. What's the difference between "a simple test class" where it's working, and the project where it isn't?

Comment: Nope. I do not do anything uncommon. This has been working for months (probably years). This has stopped working all of a sudden - not sure what action (either mine or any updates to my PC) have caused this. I am not very sure on the likeliness of the java application preventing the debugging - I see that the application itself isn't launched yet and eclipse is failing to connect to the VM. My simple test class has a main method and a test method that does a string operation. My java app: I pass in a properties file that is read by the main class to build the application components.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message as an entry in Eclipse's Debug FAQ: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Debug/FAQ#I_can_run_a_program_but_not_debug_it.3F.3F.3F

A bit of background information: Eclipse (and every other IDE) always uses a socket to connect to a JVM to debug. It doesn't matter whether the JVM is on the same computer or not. That means your IP stack has to work, security settings must allow Java to open ports, etc.

This can fail for several reasons:

1. The port is used. This usually happens when you specify a port to use instead of letting Eclipse find one for you.
2. A firewall or some other security software is denying Java to open ports
3. Your network configuration has gone bad. One case is that a trojan has added IP addresses into `/etc/hosts` (or your OS's variation of that) to redirect your traffic. For Windows, look into the folder `%WINDOWS%\system32\drivers\etc\`

   The important bit is that `localhost` resolves as `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Hello Aaron. Thank you for the information. Yes, what you said is right - every IDE uses a socket to connect to the JVM in context. Now, as I am not doing a remote debug (I am not specifying a particular port to be used), I expect eclipse to try with one of various port numbers to connect to the JVM. I have no clue on what port number eclipse could be using (so that I can check the availability of those ports). Further localhost is well resolving to 127.0.0.1 when I ping localhost (although 127.0.0.1 entry in hosts file is commented - I dont think this should matter?)

Comment: Your problem isn't Eclipse - the JVM which you **try to debug** can't open a debug port for Eclipse to connect to. Eclipse doesn't write error messages into the console - it's the program which you start that does that.